# Premake4: how to create c# solution with unit test project

Tags: c#, premake

I'm new to Premake.
I want to create a solution with 2 projects:

- a class library project
- a unit test project

I know the "kind" values are:

-ConsoleApp

-WindowedApp

-SharedLib

-StaticLib

I don't see a kind for unit test! There is a way to create this?
Below what I've done...

```
solution "MySolution"
--framework ""
configurations { "Debug","Release" }
platforms { "x32","Universal" }
    project "MyProject1"
        targetname "MyProject1"
        location "MyProject1"
        kind "SharedLib"
        language "C#"
        files { "MyProject1/**.cs" } 
        excludes { "**/bin/**", "**/obj/**" } 
        links { "System","System.Core","Microsoft.CSharp","System.Runtime.Serialization","System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" }

        configuration "Debug"
            defines { "TRACE","DEBUG" }
            flags { "Symbols" }
            targetdir "../../../../../../../deploy/bin/"

        configuration "Release"
            defines { "TRACE" }
            flags { "Optimize" }
            targetdir "../../../../../../../deploy/bin/"
```

Comment: I think the "kind" for a unit test project is "SharedLib"...but I don't know how to create a unit test project

Comment: I partially solved the problem: I've created the "unit test project" as a Shared Lib with the unit test's reference. I don't see the ampoule...but It works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution i found is to create a class library project anyway, adding it references of a common unit tests project. Then Visual Studio allow you to execute those tests. You just lack of the unit tests project icon.

I hope this will help other people!